# Create view from multiple collections that contains same data structure

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking for a solution, using MongoDB, to regroup/aggregate/whateverthenameis a specific field present in each collection inside a new collection or view.

It is my first time using MongoDB so I'm not familiar with it. What the project I've joined has, is a MongoDB database with multiple collections that save the same kind of information but from different provider.

Each collection has the field called "legalInformation" that has a name and an identifier. What we actually have in our project is an other collection, called name-id that duplicates informations from the provider's collection legalInformation. The purpose of the name-id collection is to centralize every name-id in the app, regardless of the provider. But I think that we could create a collection/view instead of programmatically duplicates those data.

I don't know what MongoDB can offer to me to achieve this. I would like to have a way to fetch and aggregate all the legalInformation from all the providers inside on collection/view.

As anyone an idea about how I could do this ?

To illustrate, this is a representation of the DB schema:

```
providerA({
  legalInformations: { name: ..., id: ... },
  specificDataFromProviderA: { ... }
})

providerB({
  legalInformations: { name: ..., id: ... },
  specificDataFromProviderB: { ... }
})

providerC({
  legalInformations: { name: ..., id: ... },
  specificDataFromProviderC: { ... }
})
```

and I want a simple collection/view called legalInformation that aggregates all legalInformations

```
legalInformation({
  name: ...,
  id: ...
})
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use `$unioinWith` to union the data from the collections together. Then use `$project` to only show the field you're interested in. If you need to remove duplicates, use `$group`. Something like the following should work:

`[
{ $unionWith : { coll: "providerA", } },
{ $unionWith : { coll: "providerB", } },
{ $unionWith : { coll: "providerC", } },
{ $project : { legalInformation : 1 } },
{ $group : { _id : "$legalInformation", legalInformation : { $name : "$id" } } },
]`